# Taking data from a google form's spreadsheet and pasting it to another google spreadsheet

Tags: google-docs

I have created a Google form that will tally distances.  On the spreadsheet of the form, I used the formula to add all of the distances that are entered.  I need to take the data from the "Total distances" cell and apply that to another Google Spreadsheet all together.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes (eg as mentioned [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43782/importrange-formula-query-to-query-data-in-another-file)).

Assuming your spreadsheet's  key (from the Form) is: `1TvTfgJaH-KpXZm-yfR2vcArcftrmhT8Z-CrIAA40C-w`
your sheet name there is: `Form Responses 1` and
the cell containing "Total distances" there is: `B6` for example:

```
=importrange("1TvTfgJaH-KpXZm-yfR2vcArcftrmhT8Z-CrIAA40C-w","Form Responses 1!B6")
```

You should be prompted to allow the connection.